# Tint Color fading when popover displayed

Tags: ios, ios7, uiview, uipopovercontroller, uicolor

I have a simple block of code wherein I am setting the tint color of a UIView. Under normal condition, this works well, but when I present a popover from somewhere, the rgb tint color fades to grayscale colors.

Once the popover is dismissed, the colors return to their normal values.

The code runs something like this:

```
UIView *view = self.imageViews[index];
view.tintColor = tintColor;
```

Is there a way to stop these colors from fading under presence of popover ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UIView has a property called tintAdjustmentMode. Did you try that out ??

A single line code like

```
view.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal;
```

could help you out in this case.

Edit: Swift 4.2 update:

```
view.tintAdjustmentMode = .normal
```

Comment: Swift 4 answer `view.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentMode.normal`

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5 update:

`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintAdjustmentMode = .normal`